# How to access elements from previously-stored estimates

Tags: stata

Say that I have use this data to run these regressions and store the output:

```
eststo clear
sysuse auto2, clear

eststo e_mpg: reg price mpg
eststo e_trunk: reg price trunk
```

I now want to be able to access the `_b` and `_se` components of `e_mpg`.

I can see them displayed by:

```
estimates replay e_mpg
```

However, running the following does not work:

```
estimates use e_mpg
```

Basically, I want to have these estimates be in the current memory so that I can access `_se[...]` and `_b[...]` or, if that is not possible, access something from `ereturn list` or `return list` or some other solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `estimates restore` instead:

```
eststo clear
sysuse auto2, clear

eststo e_mpg: regress price mpg
eststo e_trunk: regress price trunk

estimates restore e_mpg
(results e_mpg are active now)

matrix list e(b)
e(b)[1,2]
           mpg       _cons
y1  -238.89435   11253.061

display _b[mpg]
-238.89435

display _se[mpg]
53.076687
```